# how do I get google maps marker to control scrolling in jscrollpane?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jscrollpane

I have searched for an answer to this but ca only find an answer for when you want a jscrollpane in the infowindow for google maps.

I have a google map with some markers on it and each marker has an associated div in a jscrollpane div beside it. When you click on the marker on the map I want the jscrollpane to scroll to the corresponding div's Y coordinate.

Any ideas of how to do so? I cannot find much info on jscrollpane scrollto element id.

Cheers!

Comment: You will get more/better help if you share the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: **-1 this question does not show any research effort** . What you haven't found I've found after 10 seconds inside the API-documentation: [scrollToElement](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/api.html#scrollToElement)

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 pieces of information: the position of the associated div in the jscrollpane, and the jscrollpane's current scroll position.

```
var pos = $(markerDiv).position();
var currentScroll = $(scrollPane).scrollTop();
$(scrollPane).animate({ scrollTop: currentScrollTop + pos.top });
```

Alternatively, I think you could use jScrollPane's scrollTo method
    $(scrollPanel).scrollTo(currentScrollTop + pos.top);